# PHP: how to move 2 different file format to another directory at once

Tags: php, file

Here is my Code and working for 1 file format ".html"

```
// store files moved successfully
$movedFilesStatus = array();

// loop through all files
foreach ($filesToMove as $key => $fileNow) {
    $fullFilePath = File_DIR.'/'.$file_directory.$file_name.'-'.$fileNow.'.html';
    if (file_exists($fullFilePath)) {

    // moving file
    $response = moveToDir( $file_directory, $file_name, $fullFilePath, 'file_'.$fileNow);
    $cleaned = json_decode($response,true);

    // ensure that file was moved successfuly
    if ($cleaned['status'] == 200 && $cleaned['state'] == 'success' && !empty($cleaned['fullPath'])) {
    $finalStatus = 'success';
    } else {
        $finalStatus = 'failure';
        }
    }
}
```

in source directory, there are many files with html or txt format,
all html files have their own txt files, file patterns are like below:

MyHtml-XXX.html

MyHtml-XXX01234.txt ( 01234 refers to Numbers )

in my code MyHtml-XXX.html move to new directory without problem but can not modify code to move both MyHtml-XXX.html and MyHtml-XXX01234.txt together.

what is missing ?

Comment: Are all those files you want to move in `$filesToMove`, or just the html file? What does `moveToDir()` do? What does "can not modify code" mean?

Comment: @KarstenKoop yes all files are in $filesToMove, but files format is .html, 
Currently, I'm running this php file via command line, 
php mover.php MyHtml-XXX.html /path/to/dir

is it possible to add second file format to the same line?
something like this :

$fullFilePath = File_DIR.'/'.$file_directory.$file_name.'-'.$fileNow.('.html', '.txt');

 ??